# How to safely store a PC to be unused for 2 years?

Tags: windows-10, manjaro, lenovo-desktop-computer

I have a Lenovo PC (Monitor and CPU combined) and I am going to be leaving it packed for 2 years.
What precautions should I take to make sure that it boots up properly and has all the files intact (not corrupted) after 2 years? It is not going to be used by anyone or be opened at all during that time.

Here are the PC specs:-

- Type - x64-based PC
- Manufacturer - Lenovo
- Model - F0BV003TIN
- Processor - Intel Core i3-6100T @3.20GHz, 3201 Mhz, 2 Cores, 4 Logical Processors
- RAM - 8GB
- GPU - Mesa Intel HD Graphics Card 530 (3.0 Gib)
  Here are its Operating Systems:-

1. Manjaro Linux Xfce // it manages boot as well!

   - OS Name - Manjaro Linux Xfce; build ID; rolling;
   - Version - Xfce 4.16
   - 150 GB
2. Windows 10

   - OS Name - Microsoft Windows 10 Home Single Language
   - Version - 10.0.19043
   - 350 GB

Edit: A few changes to the PC after buying at around (2017-18):-

- 1tb hdd to 500gb ssd (for speed)
- 4gb ram to 8gb ram (duh for speed)

Comment: What do you mean packed? Stored in a proper storage unit, in your garden shed or in a cupboard somewhere? The components seem like it's a notebook though you tagged it desktop computer?

Comment: It misses the drive

Comment: @seth it's a "all-in-one" desktop computer

Comment: @Seth It is an all in one like PierU said!

Answer (score 0):

From the model type "F0BV003TIN" I can see that this is a all-in-one model with a HDD.

Nothing particular for this model, just general recommendations that are valid for all electronic devices: avoid storage in overheated and/or humid places (and remind that a cold place can be humid too).

The most "critical" component here can be the motherboard battery (generally a small lithium battery) that could be empty after a long time, but nothing different from a computer that is regularly used.

In theory, data retention on a SSD that is unpowered for a long time can be a problem. In practice it is hardly one, and anyway this is a HDD in your machine. And anyway you have backups of your data, right? If not, it's high time to start backing up your data...

Comment: Oh flip, i forgot to mention the changes we did to the machine:-
 -  changed ram from 4gb to 8gb
 - and changed hdd to ssd for speed

Comment: @Ninjago77 4GB or 8GB or 128GB doesn't matter here. As I wrote the only potential concern would be if it was a SSD in the machine.

Comment: Yes there is an ssd, so what should I do (other than backing up the files and data cause theres too many)

Comment: @Ninjago77 You could open the PC, remove the SSD, keep it with you during the 2 years, and powering it from time to time with a simple USB<->SATA cable (assuming it's a SATA drive). But if you care about the data that are on the disk, not making backups is complete nonsense, even without storing the computer. The disk could fail for any reason, could be stolen, could end up in a fire... External drives to make backups are cheap enough.

Comment: hmm, got it! ill try to keep the ssd w/ me